# I am getting a number of erros and warnings. Just installed Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I just started reading Charles Petzold's book Creating Mobile Apps with Xamarain.Forms but didn't get very far at all because I've hit a number of errors and warnings and am not sure how to fix them.  I have tried uninstalling Visual Studios and reinstalling it to no avail.

I am uncertain what the issue is really because I am able to build and deploy the app to my Android device for either the Portable or Shared Xamarin.Forms app.I would just like to understand what these errors are exactly and how to fix them.  If there is a resource somewhere that I can learn about them or if the answer is simple and straightforward I'd love to know.

Thanks much,

I included all the errors and warnings I got for each type of app below.

Starting with a blank Xamarin.Forms Portable app.

First dialogue error:

```
Package Installation Error 
Could not add all required packages to the project.
The following packages failed to install from 
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatfrom.5.0.0 
: Package restore failed.Rolling back pagage changes for 'App3.UWP'.
```

And in the Error List I have 12 Warnings

```
Severity    Code Description Project File    Line Suppression State
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project.Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.App3        1   Active
Warning     The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App3\App3\App3\obj\Debug\App3.dll'.
File name: 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App3\App3\App3\obj\Debug\App3.dll'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.GetFileStream(String fileName, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Compile()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() App3
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project.Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.App3.Droid      1   Active
Warning     Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com. Reason: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'App3, Version=, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?  App3.Droid          
Warning Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.App3.UWP
Warning     Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Runtime.dll'   App3.UWP c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App3\App3\App3.UWP\App3.UWP.csproj
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project.Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.App3.WinPhone       1   Active
Warning     The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App3\App3\App3.WinPhone\obj\Debug\App3.WinPhone.exe'.
File name: 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App3\App3\App3.WinPhone\obj\Debug\App3.WinPhone.exe'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.GetFileStream(String fileName, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Compile()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() App3.WinPhone
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project.Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.App3.Windows        1   Active
Warning     The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App3\App3\App3.Windows\obj\Debug\App3.Windows.exe'.
File name: 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App3\App3\App3.Windows\obj\Debug\App3.Windows.exe'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.GetFileStream(String fileName, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Compile()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() App3.Windows
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project.Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.App3.iOS        1   Active
Warning     The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App3\App3\App3.iOS\obj\iPhone\Debug\App3iOS.exe'.
File name: 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App3\App3\App3.iOS\obj\iPhone\Debug\App3iOS.exe'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.GetFileStream(String fileName, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Compile()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() App3.iOS
```

And when trying to build the solution I get 14 Errors and 8 Warnings

```
Severity Code    Description Project File Line    Suppression State
Warning The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App3\App3\App3.iOS\obj\iPhone\Debug\App3iOS.exe'.
File name: 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App3\App3\App3.iOS\obj\iPhone\Debug\App3iOS.exe'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.GetFileStream(String fileName, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Compile()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() App3.iOS
Error       Xamarin.Forms 2.0.0.6482 is not compatible with UAP, Version = v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).           0   
Error Xamarin.Forms 2.0.0.6482 is not compatible with UAP, Version= v10.0 (win10-x64).          0   
Error Xamarin.Forms 2.0.0.6482 is not compatible with UAP, Version= v10.0.          0   
Error Some packages are not compatible with UAP, Version= v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).            0   
Error Xamarin.Forms 2.0.0.6482 is not compatible with UAP, Version= v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).          0   
Error Xamarin.Forms 2.0.0.6482 is not compatible with UAP, Version= v10.0 (win10-x86).          0   
Error Some packages are not compatible with UAP, Version = v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).           0   
Error Some packages are not compatible with UAP, Version = v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).           0   
Error Some packages are not compatible with UAP, Version = v10.0 (win10-x64).           0   
Error Some packages are not compatible with UAP, Version = v10.0 (win10-arm).           0   
Error Some packages are not compatible with UAP, Version = v10.0 (win10-x86).           0   
Error Xamarin.Forms 2.0.0.6482 is not compatible with UAP, Version= v10.0 (win10-arm).          0   
Error Some packages are not compatible with UAP, Version = v10.0.           0   
Error Xamarin.Forms 2.0.0.6482 is not compatible with UAP, Version= v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).          0   
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project.Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.App3        1   Active
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project.Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.App3.Droid      1   Active
Warning     Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.App3.UWP
Warning     Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Runtime.dll'   App3.UWP c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App3\App3\App3.UWP\App3.UWP.csproj
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project.Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.App3.WinPhone       1   Active
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project.Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.App3.Windows        1   Active
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project.Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.App3.iOS        1   Active
```

I am able to debug/deploy the Xamarin.Froms Portable to my Android Device.

Also when I create a blank Xamarin.forms Shared app I get the dialog error: 
    A problem was encountered creating the sub project 'App4.UWP'.  The project requires a platform SDK (UAP, Version=10.0.10240.0) that is not installed please visit the folllowing link for more information: http://go.microsft.com/fwlink/?prd=12514&pver=14.0&sbp=PlatformSDKMissing&plcid=0x409&o1=UAP,%20Version=10.0.10240.0

Entering this url into my browser I am told the DNS address could not be found.

When it is finished creating the project I have 6 Warnings:

```
Severity Code    Description Project File Line    Suppression State
Warning The referenced component 'System.ObjectModel' could not be found.   App4.Droid
Warning     The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App4\App4\App4.Droid\obj\Debug\App4.Droid.dll'.
File name: 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App4\App4\App4.Droid\obj\Debug\App4.Droid.dll'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.GetFileStream(String fileName, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Compile()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() App4.Droid
Warning The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App4\App4\App4.WinPhone\obj\Debug\App4.WinPhone.exe'.
File name: 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App4\App4\App4.WinPhone\obj\Debug\App4.WinPhone.exe'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.GetFileStream(String fileName, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Compile()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() App4.WinPhone
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project.Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.App4.Windows        1   Active
Warning The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App4\App4\App4.Windows\obj\Debug\App4.Windows.exe'.
File name: 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App4\App4\App4.Windows\obj\Debug\App4.Windows.exe'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.GetFileStream(String fileName, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Compile()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() App4.Windows
```

When I build the solution I get 3 Warnings

```
Severity Code    Description Project File Line    Suppression State
Warning The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App4\App4\App4.iOS\obj\iPhone\Debug\App4iOS.exe'.
File name: 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App4\App4\App4.iOS\obj\iPhone\Debug\App4iOS.exe'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.GetFileStream(String fileName, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Compile()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() App4.iOS
Warning     The referenced component 'System.ObjectModel' could not be found.App4.Droid
Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project.Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.App4.Windows        1   Active
```

I am able to build and debug/deploy the Xamarin.Forms Shared to my Android device.

So what do I need to do to resolve these warnings and errors?

Comment: Hey! I've been able to reproduce this issue. I am going to research further, and will let you know of a workaround ASAP

Comment: Hey. So here is where I am. I am able to reproduce these errors via the following steps. new shared project > build > update nuget > build and each time I have solved it by doing the following (after I have received this error) close Visual Studio > Open Visual Studio > Clean Project > Build. Can you please attempt those steps, and let me know if it resolves the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have some answers, and some ways forward, for these issues. First, it should be noted that these appear to be disparate issues, but I will answer each as I can.

First, for the errors that may occur after updating NuGet Packages, those can generally be solved by cleaning the project. So steps would be: After updating packages > close Visual Studio > Open Visual Studio > Clean Project > Build

For the XAMLC error, I have created a bug on [Xamarin's bug tracking tool](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42908)

For the IDE0006 error, I have also created [a new bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42909)

For the the following error:

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatfrom.5.0.0 
: Package restore failed.Rolling back pagage changes for 'App3.UWP'.
```

I've been unable to reproduce that error. But I will kep trying. As soon as I can, I will update this post.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By updating nuget, etc., I have gotten rid of all errors except the following when compiling the "Welcome to Xamarin Forms" template - 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The referenced component 'System.ObjectModel' could not be found.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).